# Looking for a clean way to use ThreadPoolExecutor's beforeExecute and afterExecute methods with Spring's @Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Spring's `@Async` annotation and `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` are very convenient.

I am looking for a clean way to override `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` methods of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` that `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` creates a inside the `initializeExecutor` method.

Any suggestions for a clean approach to use `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` in combination with Spring's `@Async` are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Extend `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then extend `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and override  `initializeExecutor` to return an instance of your `ThreadPoolExecutor` subclass.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I see that `initializeExecutor` uses private fields of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`...

Comment: Maybe don't extend `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but instead extend its subclasses which offer some building blocks. Otherwise, implement the appropriate interfaces and provide all the behavior yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it!  Hopefully there is a clean way of doing it...  Hey, I could just copy the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` code and change one line inside `initializeExecutor` to instantiate my own `ThreadPoolExecutor` :)

Comment: What is it that you want to do in those methods? Please explain a bit more about your use case.

Comment: One use case is to track the execution time and reject new requests when certain conditions are met.